# Pandas: from crosstab to a count table

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a table of 0's and 1's generated from `pd.crosstab()`

A row is a recipe and the columns are ingredients. So for example we can have:

```
              banana mushrooms ... chocolate tuna
banana-split  1      0         ... 1         0
```

I'd like to transform it to a table where the columns and rows are both the ingredients and `T[i,j]` = #number of recipes that has both ingredients, `i` and `j`

In our example, `T[banana, chocolate] = 1` and `T[banana, tuna] = 0`

How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Definition):

```
df.T @ df
```

Comment: Thanks, can yon please give an explanation what it does? (and what is the '@' operator in this context?)

Comment: @Elimination it's the notation for matrix multiplication. See the wiki link in the updated answer. It behaves identical to dot product: `df.T.dot(df)`.